# Linux, Backtrack, Perl, Bluesniff

Tags: perl

I am trying to run bluesniff on backtrack.I have the bluesniff.pl script and when i try to execute it by typing:

```
perl bluesniff.pl
```

An error message came out:

> Can't locate Curses.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Curses/Application.pm line 92.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/Curses/Application.pm line 92.
>   Compilation failed in require at bluesniff.pl line 23.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at bluesniff.pl line 23.

Please advise!

To all who commented, thanks! It worked.

Comment: You need to install the Curses module from CPAN somehow.

Comment: Using the CPAN shell you could say: `perl -MCPAN -e 'install Curses'`

Answer (score 4):

Run

```
cpan Curses
```

from the command line to install this module and all dependencies.

Comment: In my case, I need `sudo apt install lib64ncurses-dev` (get header) first to install `Curses`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to download the [**Curses Perl module**](http://search.cpan.org/~giraffed/Curses-1.28/Curses.pm).

Answer (score 2):

You can install Curses simply by typing `apt-get install libcurses-ui-perl` if you don't need to learn and install all the Perl stack. If you prefer to, do as others said and use Cpanm to install it.